# Import and export reducer with React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm studying React-Redux and I have an example like this

```
const todoApp = combineReducers({
  todos,
  visibilityFilter
})

export default todoApp /*from reducers*/
```

then I have

```
import reducer from './reducers'

const store = createStore(reducer)

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

So, it didn't export anything as reducer in ./reducers, and the syntax import is not either `import * as reducer` in ES6. Why does it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

export default todoApp

- So whenever you "'import xyz from './reducers'" ,reducer.js will return
  todoApp beacuse by default reducer.js is returning it. No matter what
  name you give ,you can change 'import reducers from "./reducers"' to
  'import red from ./reducers' it will work in that case also .
- only one thing you should keep in mind ,that whenever importing
  default element you should avoid applying '{}' around the imported
  element . so in your case "import {reducer} from './reducer'" would
  be wrong.
- But if you write "export const todoApp" in reducers.js ,then in that
  case you have to give exact name while importing it, now you have to
  import it as 'import {todoApp} from './reducers'
- And There should be only one default export from a file.

Comment: yes, but there is no file reducers here in my project. There is only a folder named reducers, so what is the ./reducers here ?

Comment: **this code below  must be written in some file, which file it is.**   
`const todoApp = combineReducers({
  todos,
  visibilityFilter
})

export default todoApp`  
  
**combine reducers is used to combine all the reducer in your project return one reducer which is combination of all reducer ,in your case it is todoApp**

Answer (score 4):

```
export default todoApp
```

So when the `import reducer from './reducers'` is called the `todoApp` is stored inside `reducer`. Thats why we use the default keyword. The variable name doesn't need to be `reducer` it can be anything.

By using default keyword a single value or a fallback value is passed to the file that imports it

Similarly if we exported a function without default
eg

```
export function someFunc(){...}
```

We can import it by

```
import {someFunc} from '/file/path.js'
```

**EDIT** : There can only be one default export from a file. When we import other components we need to specify the component name as identifier(eg `{someFunc}`). For default imports we can use any identifier we want.

[Read more about import here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: But, from reducers, there is also another component, which was used to combineReducers , so how does it know which one would be imported ?

Comment: If there is another export component we cannot use default for that. There can only be one default export. If we want to import the other component we need to use `import componentName from './reducer.js'`.

Comment: and yet under the same folder reducers, I have 3 different components using export default. In the code I mentioned up there, `todoApp` import `todos` and `visibilityFilter` which was imported default, and then export default again, all in the same folder

Comment: ahhh okay, I understood it, but there is another problem since ./reducers file doesn't even exist, it is just a folder.

Comment: Then I guess there is an index.js file there. If there is the import statement will first will look at that file.

Answer (score 1):

When you export something as default from a module, you basically exporting an anonymous variable. So when you import anything like this `import something from 'somewhere'` the something can be any name you choose to use inside the file that does the import.

Comment: But, from reducers, there is also another component, which was used to `combineReducers `, so how does it know which one would be imported ?

Comment: combineReducers is a redux function that returns a reducer that calls every subreducer that you passed to combineReducers. So every reducer from ./reducers will be called when an action is dispatched. In your case every subreducer will receive a part of the state that has the same name as the subreducer. It is because you are calling it like `combineReducers({todos, visibilityFilter});